# What is the name of this frame?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, terminology, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I sometimes do a tensor calculations with setting $g_{\mu\nu}= \eta_{\mu\nu},\; \Gamma_\alpha{}^\lambda{}_\beta=0$. I usually call it the locally-flat frame but when I look for description about locally-flat am not sure. Am I right?

Comment: Those are Riemann normal coordinates.

Comment: Riemann normal coordinates is what you are looking for. Locally inertial or locally flat coordinates are also used by physicists, but mathematicians call this Riemannian normal coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand it correctly it is the Riemann normal coordinates or locally flat coordinate.

From [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Riemann+normal+coordinates) they described

`*Around every point of a Riemannian manifold there is a coordinate system such that the Levi-Civita connection of the metric pulled back to these coordinates vanishes at that point. (Notice that the Riemann curvature will not in general vanish even at that point).*'